# Protractor: change user agent

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, protractor

I'm testing a site designed for mobile pages. It takes screenshots of the page however the screenshots are displaying the screen like on a desktop rather than a mobile device. How can I change the user-agent of chrome (the browser I'm testing with) for these tests. I've tried this with no success:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--user-agent ="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/534.46.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/19.0.1084.60 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3"'] 
    }
},
```

The tests run, but this line seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to change the browser size to match the one of your device, for iPhone 5 Retina:

```
browser.manage().window().setSize(1136, 640);
```

Place that code within your onPrepare section.

Comment: This works. I was using this in my `beforeEach` but if i can stick in the onPrepare, even better. Since I want to use variables for sizes (from `params`) do you know how I would be able to do this?

Comment: You can open a separate question for that and put the link here, i'm glad to help.

Comment: Maybe first try reading `browser.params.width` and `browser.params.height` within that `setSize()` and add params to your config file [like Julie does here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/32#issuecomment-24355163)

Comment: That's perfect! I was having an issue with what to put before the `params.width` while within the protractor-config.js file

Answer (score 4):

The configuration syntax in Protractor seems to have changed, for me this worked (iPhone) on the recent Chrome (v38):

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4']
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I could not get certain chrome arguments to work, like setting `user-agent`.

The solution for me was to change `chromeOptions` to `goog:chromeOptions` in my protractor config.

`chromeOptions` worked when running via chromedriver on my local machine, but did not work when running on a remote Selenium instance. `goog:chromeOptions` works on both local and remote.

I am using Protractor version 5.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, couldn't pass iPhone 6 user agent while running protractor tests.
Its very simple, just go to your protractor.config.ts and add the below code for chrome capabilities

```
excludeSwitches: ['enable-automation'],
    args: ['show-fps-counter=true','--window-size=1136, 640'],
    'mobileEmulation': {
      'deviceName': 'iPhone 6'
    },
```

This works efficiently.